# Why doesn't my path update *now*?

Tags: bash, fedora, path

I recently installed the newest Qt SDK and I went ahead and added it to my PATH inside of my ~/.bash_profile.

I don't see the change.  I can `source ~/.bash_profile` but then my path is twice as long, yet I can't simply open a new gnome-terminal and have the path updated.

Why?

Notes:
Fedora 11 running GNU bash, version 4.0.16(1)-release inside of default gnome desktop.

.bash_profile path config:

```
# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/opt/qtsdk-2009.03/qt/bin/:/usr/local/lib/
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you just open a terminal from your desktop the terminal inherits the environment it was started in, including that PATH.  When you open a terminal, the following happens according to the Bash documentation:

From the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files)

> When Bash is invoked as an interactive
>   login shell, or as a non-interactive
>   shell with the --login option, it
>   first reads and executes commands from
>   the file /etc/profile, if that file
>   exists. After reading that file, it
>   looks for ~/.bash_profile,
>   ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that
>   order, and reads and executes commands
>   from the first one that exists and is
>   readable. The --noprofile option may
>   be used when the shell is started to
>   inhibit this behavior.
>
> When a login shell exits, Bash reads
>   and executes commands from the file
>   ~/.bash_logout, if it exists.

And...

> When an interactive shell that is not
>   a login shell is started, Bash reads
>   and executes commands from ~/.bashrc,
>   if that file exists. This may be
>   inhibited by using the --norc option.
>   The --rcfile file option will force
>   Bash to read and execute commands from
>   file instead of ~/.bashrc.
>
> So, typically, your ~/.bash_profile
>   contains the line
>
> ```
>  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
> ```
>
> after (or before) any login-specific
>   initializations.

So in order to get your .bash_profile to execute you need to log into a login shell, perhaps by ssh-ing into the localhost, or by logging out of your desktop environment and logging back in..

Comment: I just came across this on the man page.  You beat me to it!  Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try putting that in your `~/.bashrc` instead.

When you login, `~/.bash_profile` is processed. It is not processed again when you open a new terminal or start a new shell, which is when `~/.bashrc` is processed. You should source `~/.bashrc` in your `~/.bash_profile`.

See the "Invocation" section in `man bash`.