# Conflicts between /usr/bin and /usr/local/bin

Tags: linux, unix, ctags

I have an application ([Exuberant Ctags)](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) installed in `/usr/bin`.

I have also compiled [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) from source, which installs its own version of ctags in `/usr/local/bin`.

Running ctags from the command prompt runs the Emacs version from `/usr/local/bin`.

Is there a way to force it to use the application from `/usr/bin`?

I can go into `/usr/local/bin` and delete or rename the unwanted ctags version, but I am wondering if there is another way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Edit your PATH, so /usr/bin appears before /usr/local/bin. You find out your current path with `echo $PATH`. To change this depends on your system, usually `~/.bashrc`. There are [questions here](https://superuser.com/questions/10634/when-should-i-put-configurations-into-bashrc-vs-into-bashprofile) and on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/19495/why-is-my-bashrc-not-read-under-cygwin) [dealing](https://serverfault.com/questions/44275/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path-in-ubuntu) with where to find environment variables and which to use, `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` :-)

If you do have software installed in `/usr/local/bin/` that "overrides" what the system put in `/usr/bin`, you can create an alias to specify which executable to run on a per-program basis. For example with this ctags program, put this in your `~/.bashrc`.

```
alias ctags="/usr/bin/ctags"
```

(though one of the SF links was about cygwin specifically, it is applicable on other platforms as well)

Comment: Concise. Yet has references to basically every angle that the author would want to look at. Good post.

Comment: I think I prefer the option to set an alias to it. The whole *point* of /usr/local/bin is that it overrides the system defaults.

Comment: **Using this solution is asking for trouble** 'cuz `/usr/local` is designed to override `/usr` by the FHS. **You will lose access to any program in `/usr/local` that has a `/usr` counterpart.** `alias` only has an effect for interactive shell commands and [introduces side-effects of its own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003859/python-still-runs-the-system-version-after-virtualenv-activate) since it overrides `PATH` search.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a `ctags` installation in `/usr/local`, just delete it. (This is the best way possible 'cuz it'll save you from having to work around the problem that you're having now, ever again.)

Or prevent Emacs from installing it in the first place and/or make it check for an existing one before installing (how to do that depends on how you're installing it).

Finally, you can tell Emacs the path to `ctags` as per [EmacsWiki: Build Tags](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BuildTags#toc2), by placing

```
 (setq path-to-ctags "<path_to_ctags_executable>")
```

into your init file.