# Understanding .bashrc and .bash_profile

Tags: unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I put configurations into .bashrc vs into. .bash_profile?](https://superuser.com/questions/10634/when-should-i-put-configurations-into-bashrc-vs-into-bash-profile)

I am a n00b when it comes to working in Linux env and would like to know the purpose of `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`. I only know that they are specific to each user account. What features/behavior can be added/modified by implementing something in these files

Comment: Everyone is born as n00b. But the next step after that is to do `man bash`. I know it's a whole lot of text, but it's worth it.

Comment: -1 This question shows no research effort. It's exhaustively explained in `man bash`'s section *INVOCATION* (paragraphs 4 and 6 for me).

Comment: Also: [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](http://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile) (probably that more than the other)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, `.bash_profile` is used for login bash shells only.  `.bashrc` is used for every OTHER bash shell. Therefore, `.bash_profile` will typically source `.bashrc` if it exists so you don't have to duplicate any commands you want to run for every shell whether it was a login shell or not.

Generally speaking, there are two things you do with these scripts: Run programs and set environment variables.  Anything you want to run when you log in, you put in `.bash_profile`, anything you want to set on every shell (for instance, if you use `screen` or open a terminal) you put in `.bashrc`.

Some things from my own `.bashrc` (as an example):

- Set `$PS1`
- Enable special tab completion rules
- Set shell options by running `shopt`
- Set up command aliases

From my `.bash_profile`:

- Source `.bashrc`
- Add directories to `$PATH`
- Run `ssh-agent`

It's important to note that .bash_profile is only executed if you're directly logging in to a bash shell.  If you're starting an X session, you're logging into the X server which will have its own login script (typically something like `.xsession`)

Answer (score 4):

It's all explained in the Bash Manual in the section titled "Bash Startup Files": http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files

**UPDATE:** Here's the short version:

When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, Bash reads and executes commands from `~/.bashrc`, if that file exists.

When Bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for example, it looks for the variable `BASH_ENV` in the environment, expands its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to read and execute.

Comment: Please add more to your answer then just a link.  I am not saying the link is bad, but a quick summary would be a lot better.

Comment: @Zoredache OK, I updated my answer with a short summary of what the manual says.